# Best way to update data after an API call gets a record

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on an API where a record should only be allowed to be pulled once. It's basically a queue where once a client pulls the record, the Retrieved field on the record is marked true. The Get calls only pull records where the Retrieved field is false.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IActionResult GetAll([FromQuery] int? limit)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_repository.Get(limit));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
    public IQueryable<Report> Get(int? limit)
    {
        IQueryable<Report> reports;

        if (limit == null)
        {
            reports = _context.Reports.Where(r => r.Retrieved == false);
        }
        else
        {
            reports = _context.Reports.Where(r => r.Retrieved == false).Take((int)limit);
        }

        return reports;
    }
```

What would be the best way to modify the records that have been pulled by the Get call? If I do the modification before returning results from the repository code, then when the controller actually converts the IQueryable to real data, the field has changed and it won't pull any results, but the Controller seems like the wrong place to be doing this sort of modification to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split this functionality away from the retrieval. Let the caller/client indicate that the report has been successfully retrieved and read with a second call. It is a little more overhead but it adds resilience. Example: if there is a failure in the retrieval after the server call (*maybe in the network on browser or client app*) then the client has another opportunity to retrieve the data.

Controller:

```
[HttpPut] 
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> MarkAsRetrieved(IEnumerable<int> reportIds, CancellationToken token)
{
    await _repository.MarkRetrievedAsync(reportIds, token).ConfigureAwait(true);
    return Ok();
}
```

Repository:

```
public Task MarkRetrievedAsync([FromBody]IEnumerable<int> reportIds, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (Report report in reportIds.Select(x => new Report{ReportId = x, Retrieved = false}))
    {
        _context.Reports.Attach(report);
        report.Retrieved = true;
    }
    return _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
}
```

### Notes

- It is only necessary to send over the identifier for a `Report` instance. You can then attach an empty instance with that same identifier and update the `Retrieved` property to `true`, just that will be sent in the corresponding store `update` statement.

Comment: I like this strategy, but when I try this, I get an error that the report is already attached on the _context.Reports.Attach(report) line.

Comment: @KevenDenen - also an option, the downside to that is that you are retrieving the reports only to then update them again, its basically a double step where the retrieval is actually not necessary. If the type Report is light weight its not a big deal, if it has big columns like large strings then its a lot of overhead.

Comment: @KevenDenen - the only reason I could see that happening is: 1) there is a double id passed through, you could filter that out with `reportIds.Distinct().Select(...`. 2) Your context is stale or is the same context instance on which the retrieval was called.

Comment: It was the context that was the issue. I set up the context in the Startup.cs file as a service. I had just called an HttpGet to retrieve a list, so the context was already filled with the reports. If I restart the API and call the HttpPut without first calling HttpGet, there is no error with your code.

Comment: @KevenDenen - good deal. There is an extension method that you can use in core to inject the context into your services/controllers as a new instance for each request which is what you want, otherwise you are going to experience all sorts of race condition bugs as soon as you have more than 1 user calling the site. I wish I remembered what the name is off the top of my head but I think its in a default template somewhere when you create a new mvc core web project.

Comment: Ahha, that was the issue. I had setup the ReportRepository as a Singleton, changing that to a scoped service fixed that right up.

Comment: The decoration for getting the data from the body of the call is [FromBody], ie public async virtual Task<IActionResult> MarkAsRetrieved([FromBody]int[] ids)

Comment: Hmm...passing in an invalid Id results in an error (expected to affect 1 row, but affected 0 rows) when using your code. I don't expect to ever get invalid Ids, but this could be one benefit of selecting from the context in that you are guaranteed to only attempt to interact with valid rows.

Comment: @KevenDenen - in that case *if* the type `Report` was bloated or could be bloated (ie. many columns or large data values like strings or bytes) you could do a select on an anonymous object and only pull back the id and retrieved state and then do the update to keep it lean.

Answer (score 0):

I would changed the `Retrieved` bit in the database to a handle of some kind-- Guid or record id to another table that records the fetch, or some other unique value.  Then I would determine the handle, update the records I am about to fetch with that that handle, then retrieve the records that match that handle.  At any point if you fail, you can set the retrieved handle back to NULL for the handle value you started.